# kotlin-jpa plugin not generating default constructor

Tags: java, jpa, kotlin

I am using kotlin-jpa to generate default constructor to my kotlin entity, however, does are not being generated:

I just used:

`id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.jpa") version "1.3.21"`

---

```
@Entity
data class PlanSubscription(@Id ...
```

But event with the kotlin-jpa plugin the constructor is not generated:

`No default (no-argument) constructor for class`

Comment: You shouldn't use data classes for entities: the toString/hashCode/equals don't fit for entities, and entities should be open to support lazy-loading based on dynamic proxies.

Comment: What's the status of the question @Guilherme Torres Castro?

Comment: @Skizo-ozᴉʞS Sorry for the delay. I made a mistake and pasted the wrong plugin `kotlin.jvm` Instead of `kotlin jpa`. I edit the question to reflect that I'm already using the kotlin jpa plugin, but the no-arg constructors are not being generated.

Comment: You need to define an empty constructor, can you please add a default constructor for your class and try it again?

Comment: @Skizo-ozᴉʞS But that what the kotlin-jpa is supposed to do

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar issue.  While the advice of not using data classes may or may not be a useful one I found that it was the version of the jpa plugin that was at issue try using version 1.3.41

`id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.jpa" version "1.3.41"`

Answer (score 0):

You need to set

```
`<dependency>
   <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
   <artifactId>kotlin-reflect</artifactId>
   <version>1.1.0</version>
</dependency>`
```

in your pom.xml